# OOTB Granite Render Condition in AEM

Tags: aem

I have created a button called `annotation` and I have added `hasannotation` OOTB granite render condition. On selection of an image having annotation, the button doesn't get rendered.
[Image Of the custom button with granite:rendercondition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQuZg.png)

[Properties of the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2nhA.png)

[Properties of granite:rendercondition node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCm1e.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to add granite:rel property to your button. 
As said in the [documentation](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/granite-ui/api/jcr_root/libs/granite/ui/docs/server/commonattrs.html):

> This is used to indicate the semantic relationship of the component
>   similar to HTML rel attribute.

You can add the AEM existing granite:rel in your custom button as "aem-assets-admin-actions-annotate-activator" as shown /libs/dam/gui/content/assets/jcr:content/actions/selection/annotate

Or you can also add your custom value lets say "my-annotation-rel". In this case you need to tell AEM to consider your custom value. In order to do this, you need to overlay /libs/dam/gui/coral/components/admin/contentrenderer/base/assetBase.jsp
and add this line :

```
 actionRels.add("my-annotation-rel");
```

**Update:** render condition is not working because the path is not correctly passed to redercondition component. {requestPathInfo.suffix} does not give the actual path of the asset rather it gives the folder path and hence it fails to check when you are in card/column/list view.

In order to implement this, follow these steps:

1. Overlay /libs/dam/gui/coral/components/admin/contentrenderer/base/base.jsp
2. Add this below code inside getActionRels(Node node, boolean hasReplicate,boolean hasRemoveNode, boolean hasModifyAccessControl, boolean isExpiredAsset, boolean isExpiredSubAsset, boolean isDAMAdmin, boolean isContentFragment) method

   ```
   boolean hasAnnotation = false;
   NodeIterator nodeItr= node.getNodes();

     Node commentsNode;
     while(nodeItr.hasNext()) {
         Node childNode = nodeItr.nextNode();
         NodeIterator childItr = childNode.getNodes();
         while(childItr.hasNext()) {
             Node secondLevelChild = childItr.nextNode();
             if(secondLevelChild.getName().equals("comments")) {
                 NodeIterator thirdLevelNode = secondLevelChild.getNodes();    
                 while(thirdLevelNode.hasNext()){
                 if(thirdLevelNode.nextNode().hasProperty("annotationData")){
                      hasAnnotation = true;
                    }
                 }
              }
         }
       }
       if(hasAnnotation){
               actionRels.add("my-annotation-rel");
     }
   ```
3. Add granite:rel (String) "my-annotation-rel" property to your custom button

It should work.

Another way without changing the OOTB jsp file behaviour, if you are customising metadataeditor then granite render condition should work . In this case you have to first overlay this and your custom button:

```
 /libs/dam/gui/content/assets/metadataeditor/jcr:content/actions
```

and add granite:rendercondition node under your custom button and give path property as

```
 ${empty requestPathInfo.suffix ? param.item : requestPathInfo.suffix}
```

Comment: hasannotations is present in `/libs/dam/gui/coral/components/commons/renderconditions/hasannotations/hasannotations.jsp` . It checks if the image is annotated or not(contains child node named comment). If it is annotated then it renders the button, else it doesn't. How will granit:rel help in rendering?

Comment: if you do not mention granit:rel then your custom button in menu bar will not be shown and after that your renderconditions comes into action

Comment: I have added the property to my button, on selection of the image that has annotation, the button still doesnt appear. I have to clear the cache 3-4 times and then its rendering, again if I click on any other picture, I have to clear the cache many times then it gets hidden. Is this due to cache issue or render condition issue?

Comment: I have followed the 3 steps as provided in the updated answer, but on selection of the image I still don't see the button getting rendered in the ActionBar.

Comment: @ShaheenaSk, you might be doing something wrong, it works for me. pls follow the steps correctly.